# State Error CS0501 'MoviesController.Random()' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial WebApplication1

Tags: c#

**
    I can’t find the error, I’ve already completely redone the project, but this error still gets out, what is the problem of the guys.
**

```
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Web;
   using System.Web.Mvc;
   using WebApplication1.Models;

   namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
   {
   public class MoviesController : Controller
   {
   // GET: Movies/Random
   public ActionResult Random();

   public ActionResult ByReleaseDate(int year, int month)
   {

       enter code here

   return Content(year + "/" + month);
   }
   }
```

Comment: Did you try to compile your code? "enter code here"

Comment: Problem is here: `public ActionResult Random();` it does not have body which is kind of `{ return View() }` or whatever it should return

Answer (score 1):

The `Exception` is telling you what the error is, you need to declare a body for the method `Random()`:

```
//Error, no body for the method
public ActionResult Random();

//Resolve error
public ActionResult Random()
{
    return someActionResult;
}
```

Comment: Even with your code does not work

Comment: @ДамирМеретуков It has to return an `ActionResult` object. `someActionResult` is just an example name for  the actual object. And "Even with your code does not work" doesn't help. Are you still getting the same error?

Comment: Yes, problem don't resolved.I just watch a video clip and it shows how to write everything there, it works for me, but I don’t